# d3 svg circle placement on x, y

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, d3.js, svg

I'm pretty new to d3 and fairly inexperienced with svg objects and I'm trying to place d3 generated circle elements on a page. I've followed several different tutorials and kinda mixed them all together and can't figure out why my current code doesn't work. html below;

```
<body>
<div id="svgDiv"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/App/test.js"></script>

</body>
```

And the javascript (test.js)

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowLength = $(window).height();

var yPos = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];

var base = d3.select("#svgDiv").append("svg")
  .attr("width", windowWidth)
  .attr("height", windowLength);


$(document).ready(function () {

windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowLength = $(window).height();

base.attr("width", windowWidth)
    .attr("height", windowLength);
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

});

$(window).resize(function () {

windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowLength = $(window).height();
base.attr("width", windowWidth)
   .attr("height", windowLength);

});


$("div").click(function (e) {

base.selectAll("circle")
    .data(yPos)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return yPos[i];
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return yPos[i];
    })
    .attr("cx", 20)
    .attr("cy", 20)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("fill", "00ACCD");

console.log("click works");
});
```

So this should (and does) generate 5 svg circles on click at x and y = 50, 100, 150... 250 but all 5 circles are placed on top of each other in the top left of the page.

Any insight into this behaviour would be greatly appreciated, my primary language is C#.net and d3 really doesn't seem to be clicking with me at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you have `attr("x", function...` change to `cx`, the same for `y`, changing to `cy`, and remove those two `.attr("cx", 20).attr("cy", 20)` at the end. Also, since you're new to D3, here's a free advice: **don't mix D3 and jQuery**!!!

Comment: That's got it! Thank you so much, clearly I need to go back over the difference between cy and y on circles again. Thanks for the advice, I'll remove jQuery!

Comment: Yes, please do that! Use jQuery for jQuery things and D3 for D3 things... that mix of jQuery and D3 gives me headaches! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an answer to the question. (@Gerardo has addressed it in the comments.)

Use attributes `cx` and `cy` to position the SVG circles, instead of `x` and `y`. (See [Mike Bostock's circle tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)) Here is [the fix](https://github.com/yucigou/stackoverflow-ref-projects/commit/cdcc1c3d71a74fe3b47882f15b5517e27d96c379#diff-702a498516be4c46730a1d35d9bfb69a):

[image]

In the click event for this question, you'll see the circles as below, not on top of each other:

[image]